# Bash: using parameter expansion to add variables at front and end simultaneously

Tags: linux, bash

How can i use parameter expansion to add strings at front and end at the same time.
Currently i'm doing this in two steps:

```
base_test_path=something
folder=anotherthing
test=(abc cde)

halfPaths=("${test[@]/#/$base_test_path}")
fullPath=("${halfPaths[@]/%//$folder/}")
```

can i eliminate one step here.

Comment: What's wrong in doing in 2 steps?

Comment: im just asking if this is possible.

Comment: Your attempts look good and you should really use that

Comment: @PepeHands, I totally agree with Inian here, in spite of doing it shortcut you should follow step by step process since tomorrow if someone is going through code it will help them also to understand too.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the explanation!